# "role discovery data is unavailable" in Compute Emulator with > 1 instance (in Web Role)

Tags: azure

On VS2010 SP1 with Azure 1.4 SDK

Create a new Azure Project and a single Web Role, in Page_Load of default.aspx.cs add:

```
string id = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id;
Response.Write("CurrentRoleInstance.Id: " + id);
```

This works, now change Instance count to 2 or more.

role discovery data is unavailable "InvalidOperationException"

Why is this?

This works fine on deployment to Azure.

Answer (score 0):

Do ran your application on Azure compute emulator? This error occurred when not ran on Azure instance or compute emulator.

If possible, Could you change page_load method follows:

```
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (RoleEnvironment.IsAvailable)
        {
            string id = RoleEnvironment.CurrentRoleInstance.Id;
            if (RoleEnvironment.IsEmulated)
            {
                Response.Write("(Emulator) CurrentRoleInstance.Id: " + id);
            }
            else
            {
                Response.Write("(Azure Platform) CurrentRoleInstance.Id: " + id);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Not run on azure environment");
        }

    }
```